# GoogleSlides-php-lib Update Paragraph Style class missing?

Tags: php, google-slides-api

Trying to change the paragraph style of various shapes and tables on slides in order to align the text [as per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#UpdateParagraphStyleRequest)

However looking both on [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/Slides) and in my local vendor I cannot seem to find the UpdateParagraphStyleRequest class?

My composer.json requires:

`"google/apiclient-services" : "dev-master",
"google/apiclient" : "^2.0",`

With `google/apiclient-services = 8ec364f`

Comment: UpdateParagraphStyle was added recently, and it looks like the Slides php client on github hasnt updated yet. It should appear soon.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just checking I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: It's included in this PR: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/pull/52

Comment: Brilliant, will use that for now. Thank you